CRYSTALS-Kyber Central Binomial Distribution reference inplementation in c

In lines 8 to 10, why it does not get input bytes as it is (i.e., line 8)? It first does some changes (line 9 and 10).
Do authors do this changes as we cannot work with binary form of a variable easily in C language? (With these changes (line 9 and 10), for example for $j=i=0$ in lines 13 and 14 we have: $a=(d_{1}d_{0})_{2}=(0t_{1})_{2}+(0t_{0})_{2};\qquad t_{0},t_{1}\in\{0,1\}\Rightarrow a\in\{0,1,2\}$ which generates legit values for $a$ as in line 3 of the pseudocode)
Why authors get variable $a$ and $b$, (siged) $int16\_t$
and not $uint16\_t$? The sum of some binary values (lines 3 and 4 of the pseodocode) is non-negative, isn't it?

In the following code of cbd.c in [CRYSTALS website, Resources, NIST submission package for round 3, .zip file]
1. static void cbd2(poly *r, const uint8_t buf[2*KYBER_N/4])
2. {
3.   unsigned int i,j;
4.   uint32_t t,d;
5.   int16_t a,b;
6. 
7.   for(i=0;i<KYBER_N/8;i++) {
8.     t  = load32_littleendian(buf+4*i);
9.     d  = t & 0x55555555;
10.    d += (t>>1) & 0x55555555;
11. 
12.    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
13.      a = (d >> (4*j+0)) & 0x3;
14.      b = (d >> (4*j+2)) & 0x3;
15.      r->coeffs[8*i+j] = a - b;
16.    }
17.   }
18. }

Line 8: Let $t=0bt_{31}t_{30}t_{29}t_{28}\ldots t_{3}t_{2}t_{1}t_{0}$
Line 9: $d=t\ \text{bit-wise AND}\ 0b0101 \ldots 0101 = 0b0t_{30}0t_{28} \ldots 0t_{2}0t_{0}$
Line 10: $(t\ \text{one bit right shift})\ \text{bit-wise AND}\ 0b0101 \ldots 0101 = 0b0t_{31}0t_{29} \ldots 0t_{3}0t_{1}$
Here is the pseudocode in [CRYSTALS-Kyber website, Resources, Specification document (version 3.02)]

Algorithm 2 $\mathsf{CBD}_{\eta}: \mathcal{B}^{64\eta} \rightarrow R_{q}$ 
Input: Byte array $B = (b_{0},b_{1},\ldots,b_{64\eta−1}) \in \mathcal{B}^{64\eta}$ 
Output: Polynomial $f \in R_{q}$ 
1-  $(\beta_{0},\dots, \beta_{512\eta−1}) := \mathsf{BytesToBits}(B)$ 
2-  for $i$ from $0$ to $255$ do 
3-     $a := \sum_{j=0}^{\eta-1} \beta_{2i\eta+j}$ 
4-     $b := \sum_{j=0}^{\eta-1} \beta_{2i\eta+\eta+j}$ 
5-     $f_{i} := a − b$ 
6-  end for 
7- return $f_{0} + f_{1}X + f_{2}X^{2} +\ldots + f_{255}X^{255}$

And here is the definition of centered binomial distribution:

Sampling from a binomial distribution. Noise in Kyber is sampled from a centered binomial distribution $B_{\eta}$ for $\eta=2$ or $\eta=3$. We define $B_{\eta}$ as follows:
Sample $(a_{1},\ldots,a_{\eta}; b_{1},\ldots,b_{\eta})\leftarrow \{0,1\}^{2\eta}$ and output $\sum_{i=1}^{\eta}(a_{i}−b_{i})$.


For your second question, $a$ and $b$ both easily fit into a signed 16 bit integer, and one is computing $a - b$ later, which may be negative. It makes some sense to me to just work with signed arithmetic for that while part of the computation then.

Not that it matters for 2-complement integers anyway. Addition and subtraction works exactly the same - including wrapping around at the edges, although the result is of course interpreted differently. But bitwise you'd get the same value. Now C++ didn't require 2-complement originally, but since at least C++11 int16_t must be two complement.
